# How to express Bayesian Network or Markov Random Field using deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, bayesian-network, tensorflow, markov-random-field

Bayesian Nework and Makov random field are instances of general probabilistic graphical model.

Is it possible to express Bayesian Network or Markov Random Field using deep learning? or in general to express factor graph using deep learning tools like tensorflow/caffee?

Comment: Perhaps look [here](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/graphical_models.html) to start.

Answer (score 0):

Not the graphical models themselves, but the graphs (DAG and UG) that underly the models. E.g. for UGs you can use graph neural nets (GNN).